# Proving that self-adjoint operators have only real eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

Does anyone know how to prove that if $T$ is a self-adjoint operator, then all of the eigenvalues of $T$ are real?

Comment: Refer this. http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_of_Self-Adjoint_Operator_are_Real

Comment: how do you define self-adjoint operators?

Answer (score 1):

$Tx=\lambda x,\ x\not=0\implies \langle Tx,x\rangle=\langle \lambda x,x\rangle =\lambda\langle x,x\rangle$ so  $\overline{\langle Tx,x\rangle}=\overline{\langle \lambda x,x\rangle}=\overline{\lambda\langle x,x\rangle}=\overline{\lambda}\langle x,x\rangle$. But by conjugate symmetry of the inner product followed by the fact that $T$ is self-adjoint, $\overline{\langle Tx,x\rangle}=\langle x,Tx\rangle=\langle Tx,x\rangle$ which, from the work above, implies $\lambda=\overline{\lambda}$, i.e. $\lambda\in\mathbb R$.